# Bypass double quotes " transformed to &quot;

Tags: xss

I'm having a hard time bypassing `&quot;`

I tried every payload but nothing happened. The payload is

```
"><img src="data:xxx1" style='aaa: '\"/onerror=alert(1)//'' />
```

But it's transformed to

```
<input class="td-widget-search-input" type="text" value="`&quot;><img src=&quot;data:xxx1&quot; style='aaa: '\&quot;/onerror=alert(1)//'' />`
```

*I knew 1 thing if I can inject just 1 other " like this in the value*

```
value="**"**><img src`=&quot;data:xxx1&quot; style='aaa: '\&quot;/onerror=alert(1)//'' />`
```

It will work. So my question is, is there is a way to bypass it?

Answer (score 2):

In general, no.

If you see `"` getting transformed to `&quot;` as it passes through the HTML, then that usually means that the application is doing output escaping properly. You *may* be able to find another part of the app (another page, widget, HTML element, etc) that forgot to do HTML escaping, but in general that means the app is well-built.

Keep hunting! You're on the right track!